# Implementing rails view helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, helper

I'm trying to make a simple helper but can't seem to get it to run. Here is what I'm doing:

### view:

```
<td><%= assignment.status %></td>
```

I'm simply iterating through all assignments and trying to call this status method that I have in a helper. Here is the helper:

### HELPER

```
 module AssignmentHelper
  def status(assignment)
    if assignment.finished
      "Finished"
    else
      "Waiting"
    end
  end
end
```

### ERROR

[image]

It's telling me status is undefined.. Am I not defining it in the helper? any help would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it like this.

```
<td><%= status(assignment) %></td>
```